# How open an other activity apps with my application?

Tags: android, android-intent, podcast

I want to know how can i open the MixCLoud application ( -> [LINK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixcloud.player) ) from my apps. As you may know, this is an application like deezer, who play audio podcast. I have a url "URL" of a podcast from the MixCLoud website, and from my Application i want to open MixCLoud with the URL, to play that podcast without search it in the app.

My code is like that :

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mixcloud.player"); // mixcloud package
            Uri u = Uri.parse(URL);
            i.setData(u);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
```

And of course, it open Mixcloud but on the main page.
If anyone knows how open MixCloud app directly on the podcast, I need your help!

thanks!

PS : Sorry for the langage error, english is not my lative langage.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't launch a specific intent because the `packageManager` will return just the intent that have the `intent-filter` `CATEGORY_LAUNCH` . refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303793/android-possible-to-start-any-activity-of-other-apps-from-my-own)

instead , to launch an app from your app try this  :

```
protected void startAppFromPackageName(String packageName) {
        Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (mIntent != null) {
            try {
                startActivity(mIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
                Log.i(TAG, "the App : " + packageName + " is not installed");
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.i(TAG, "the App : " + packageName + " is not installed");
        }
    }
```

and call it like this :

```
startAppFromPackageName("com.mixcloud.player");
```